# Bypassing exchange accounts while sending mail through SMTP Server in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, imap, exchange-server

I develop applications using the ASP.NET framework for my academic organization. We also have an exchange server for internal accounts. 
Since my organization is under the umbrella of a larger one, all our internal exchange accounts also have external parent accounts with the same names. 
I'm facing an issue where automatic emails triggered using the system.net.mail classes are correctly routed to the required email addresses, but they go into exchange account's inbox.
While this is not a big problem for some users, there are a few who want the emails to go to the parent accounts so that they can view emails while working from home.

I was wondering if there is any way I can achieve this at the application layer - to instruct the SMTP server to send mails to the external accounts with the same names and ignore the local active directory accounts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The SMTP protocol doesn't have any spec for this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to setup and point to an alternate relay for this to happen.